# Typescript definition for function and object with the same name

Tags: typescript

loadingOverlay below acts as both a function and an object that contains another function called 'close'. How would this be declared in a Typescript definition file?

```
USAGE
$.cmp.loadingOverlay("Please wait...");
$.cmp.loadingOverlay.close("Please wait...");

DECLARATIONS
$.cmd.loadingOverlay = function(message) { ... }
$.cmd.loadingOverlay.close = function(message) { ... }
```

Declaring loadingOverlay just as a function was pretty straight forward but I cannot figure out how to add the close method.

```
interface JQueryStatic {
    cmp: {
        loadingOverlay(message: string): JQuery;
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
interface JQueryStatic {
  cmp: {
    loadingOverlay: {
      (message: string): JQuery;
      close(message: string): void;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I knew it would make sense when I saw the answer. Thank you.